# Finding $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(3+(-1)^k)^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

The series $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(3+(-1)^k)^k}=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{16^2}-\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{16^3}-\frac{1}{2^7}+\frac{1}{16^4}-.........$$
can be seen as difference of two infinite convergent geometric series as
$$S=\left(1+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16^2}+\frac{1}{16^3}+\frac{1}{16^4}.....\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^7}+....\right)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{16}}-\frac{1/2}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{2}{5}.$$
Curioisly the Mathematica doesn't yield this summation. The question: Is  this sum  all well?

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: Seems to be fine. Sometimes a CAS needs a little nudge to evaluate tricky things. I'll let someone else get the rep points here if they can find another way.

Comment: Thanks, but what is CAS?

Comment: CAS stands for Computer Algebra System.

Comment: Thanks for this expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Somewhat more elaborated we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(3+(-1)^k\right)^k}}
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2N-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(3+(-1)^k\right)^k}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{\left(3+(-1)^{2k}\right)^{2k}}
+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{\left(3+(-1)^{2k+1}\right)^{2k+1}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{4^{2k}}
-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{16^N}}{1-\frac{1}{16}}
-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{4^N}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{16}}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{2}{5}}
\end{align*}
With (2) the only crucial step where we argue that if both limits exist, then the sum of both limits exist and is equal to the limit (1) of the sum.